# Drools match pattern with variable

Tags: drools

I try to write a rule which compares an ISO-Country-Code with a List of ISO-Codes in a String (comma-separated).

The when-part of the Rule looks like this:

```
rule "TEST"
when
    $s :SCC();
    $f : Fund()
    (exists(
        RegulationGroup(
        (CI matches ".*" + $s.clientDomicile + ".*")
        ) from $f.regulationGroups
    ))
```

CI is a list of Countries (eg. "DE,AT,GB") and I try to match this against a single ISO-Code which is represented by $s.clientDomicile.

The above syntax does not work. Error Message:
text=Predicate 'CI ~= ".*" + $s.clientDomicile + ".*"' must be a Boolean expression

How can I include a Variable/Data-Point in the "Matches"-Pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the operator precedence requires you to parenthesize the concatenation. This works in 6.4.0:

```
rule "TEST"
when
  $s: SCC( $cd: clientDomicile )
  $f: Fund( $rg: regulationGroups )
  exists RegulationGroup( CI matches (".*\\b" + $cd + "\\b.*") ) from $rg
then ...  end
```

I prefer bindings to stand out in the pattern to which they belong.

The `\b` may be an overkill for the ISO codes, but they won't hurt.

Comment: works fine with the additional brackets, you are absolutely right. Thanks!